# Kubernete NAT pod IP on Windows Nodes

Tags: windows, kubernetes, nodes

I have a hybrid GKE Cluster running with some Linux and Windows nodes. I followed this how-to (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent) in order to configure the masquerade for some of my networks and it works like a charm on Linux Nodes. But it doesn't work on the windows hosts, it gives me this error:

```
Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "ip-masq-agent-pc9vn": Error response from daemon: network host not found
```

Anyone knows how can I configure masquerade on Windows Nodes?

**Adding details:**

I know that Linux containers don't run on Windows nodes, so ip-masq-agent won't run on that node and I know that I can use taints or labels to avoid the pods to be scheduled on that node.

I use Windows nodes with kubernetes because I have some .Net Framework applications running on it, and it works fine. My problem is that I need to masquerade the connections from the pod to hosts outside of the cluster because the source connections are the Pod IPs, not the node IP.

On Linux machines, I can do that using ip-masq-agent, that mange Iptables rules to masquerade the traffic. But on Windows, the ip-masq-agent doesn't work, for the reasons that @Rico said in his answer.

I want to know if someone knows another way to achieve the same thing on Windows nodes.

I can use a "NAT Machine" holding all connections in the middle and route all traffic to that machine, but it's a really ugly way to do that.

**Solution:**
I end up allowing the pod network to go through VPN. Thank you for all the replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't. iptables is a Linux thing. Windows has some alternatives that you can use to set up NAT (`netsh`) like described here: https://superuser.com/questions/1088309/windows-10-nat-port-forwarding-ip-masquerade, but there's no specific K8s support so you will be on your own.

To make sure your `ip-masq-agent` doesn't get scheduled on your Windows nodes you can follow a `NodeSelector`, `Taint/Toleration` approach as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/user-guide-windows-containers/#ensuring-os-specific-workloads-land-on-the-appropriate-container-host).

A wider question would be what are you trying to run on the Windows machines? [Windows containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/user-guide-windows-containers/#ensuring-os-specific-workloads-land-on-the-appropriate-container-host) are not interchangeable with Linux containers. If you want your Linux pods and Windows pods to talk to each other have you tried [Flannel](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/adding-windows-nodes/#getting-started-adding-a-windows-node-to-your-cluster)?

Comment: Hello Rico, thank you for your answer.

I think I wasn't able to explain my question in the right way, so I added more details on the answer and now I think you'll understand my issue :).

Comment: yeah, you can try `netsh`